# Magento 2 - ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Tags: magento2, bug

I suddenly get "**ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE**" on my website. I have no clue how to debug it.
Nothing new is added to the servers error log if I attempt to reload.

I tried clearing the cache.

I also set the rights with:

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

It started after changing deploy mode from production to developer.

Comment: did you try to execute setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile ?

Comment: Yes, did not helped.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if I change back to `production` mode, then it works again...

So it seems to be impossible to change back from production to developer or default mode.

I will report it as a bug.